# Codeigniter url rewriting replacind id with product name

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-url

I am trying to rewrite the url for my project but not sure if it is at all possible.

The current url is: `http://localhost/mu/shoe/individualShoe/21`
and I want it to be `http://localhost/mu/shoe/Puma-Rockstar` (Where the id is replaced with the product name).

Please let me know if this is at all possible.

Thanks Rockstars!

Answer (score 0):

have you try http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

you can also read http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

than try ;)

http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/